# Rotating HubTile in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone 8 application i am using HubTile control. Is there any way to change the speed of rotation of HubTile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean HubTile from Silverlight toolkit for Windows Phone you can't control speed of rotation.

Some information:

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api

You can create your own control same to HubTile and set speed for it. Check:

http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/29/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-29-animations/

Comment: He source for the Toolkit is available so if you really wanted to, you could get that and modify the speed at which it flips.

Comment: @Aneesh The WP toolkit source code is here: http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest